# How do I open Kotlin file from GitHub in Intellij Idea?

Tags: github, kotlin

I wrote code that works, I uploaded whole project file on GitHub, and when I download it again (with link), I can't run my code. How can I solve that?

Comment: from* I misspelled it in title

Answer (score 0):

If you use Gradle or Maven you should import your project after download.

For gradle:
Click right button on a build.gradle and then click "Import Gradle Project"

For maven:
Click right button on a pom.xml and then click "Add as Maven project"

Comment: Can you somehow message me?